# How can i filter out a comma in a TextBoxExtender in ASP.NET AJAX Toolkit?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, toolkit, textboxextender

I want my TextBoxExtender to NOT allow a comma and a slash. How do I set it ? Using an escape sequence ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for the *InvalidChars* Element. The FilteredTextBoxExtender can be set to filter either Valid or Invalid Characters.

```
   <ajaxToolkit:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="MyId" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="TextBoxName"         
        FilterType="Custom"
        FilterMode="InvalidChars"
        InvalidChars="Your Charcters" />
```

[Reference](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx)

EDIT no you can just add all your characters you want to exclude

```
InvalidChars="`~!@#$%^&*()_-+=[]{}:;',.<>/? "
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , but i also wanted to know how to include a comma in the set - it needs an escape sequence right ? Like Invalidchars="H,\,".